# Automatically Adjust Height Showing Slide Content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

I am using angular and angular animate to hide and show content with a slide up/down effect - similar to jQuery show.

However, this worked well when i had one slide. Now i have multiple, with varying sizes, how can i adjust the code so the height of the element to show (div or form) is automatially calcuated and adjusted rather than being predefined?

HTML:

```
<h2 ng-click="showSpoons = !showSpoons">Show Spoons +</h2>
<div ng-show="showSpoons" class="animate-slide-up">
  <p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p>
  <p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p>
  <p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p>
  <p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p><p>Spoon</p>
</div>
<br>
<h2 ng-click="showForks = !showForks">Show Forks +</h2>
<div ng-show="showForks" class="animate-slide-up">
  <p>Fork</p><p>Fork</p><p>Fork</p>
  <p>Fork</p><p>Fork</p><p>Fork</p>
</div>
<br>
<h2 ng-click="showCups = !showCups">Show Cups +</h2>
<div ng-show="showCups" class="animate-slide-up">
  <p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p>
  <p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p>
  <p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p>
  <p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p>
  <p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p><p>Cups</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-hide-add, .ng-hide-remove {
    /* ensure visibility during the transition */
    display: block !important; /* yes, important */
}

.animate-slide-up {
    transition: .25s linear all;
    height: 10em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.animate-slide-up.ng-hide {
    height:0;
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/t7oVw3n3oTxuPaPLo38a?p=preview

Comment: Try setting `min-height: 10em;` instead of `heigh: 10em;`

Comment: you really want the slides to be all the same size or it will bounce the page. or you can use extra min whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much defining a fixed `height` value for your slides. Instead of using fixed values, you may use `height: auto;`. This will provide your slide an automagically generated height value, according to the slides content. So basically, what you need is this:

```
.animate-slide-up {
    transition: .25s linear all;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GLgoWn8ggg7jQGN4osS6?p=preview)

Use this,

```
.animate-slide-up {
    transition: .25s linear all;
    min-height: 10em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you have only 1 <p> element this won't work properly, since a short text wouldn't need to have a height of 10em. That being said, that's not the proper way to handle that.

Comment: this min height is example.. user can set less than this as well..or set it to auto.